# mix left shifter and font derailleur of different speed

Tags: derailleur

I have a Shimano 5700 front derailleur and 5700 flat bar shifter (left) but for some reason I can't use the FD on my frame (too narrow, my driven train is 9 speed). After lot of research some people suggest using Shimano 2400 FD (8 speed). I am going to try but my question is can I still use the 5700 flat bar shifter (left), which is for 10 speed driven train?

Comment: If you have a 9 speed drive train then why would you go to an 8 speed?  I am surprised the rear is working - good for you.

Comment: If you have a 9 speed drivetrain, why do you have a 5700 shifter in the first place?

Comment: I have a 1 x 9 system now want to convert to 2 x 9, As I don't want to go 2 x 10 for now so want to keep the components for the '9' as many as possible. But 9 speed crank sets are harder to get, so I got a 5700 10 speed, but I have to keep the 9 speed chain for the cassette. But then I found the FD is too narrow and too faraway from the frame so I googled and saw some people using the 8 speed FD because it's wider and closer to frame (I am not sure, I haven't got one).

Comment: The front derailer is generally not nearly as fussy as the rear with regard to the "match" between shifter and derailer.  This is doubly true for a 2x front vs a 3x.  But, lacking appropriate specs (which are hardly ever available), the only way to know for sure is to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work OK while you should not mix 2 & 3 speed (MTB and road) front gears. 8 speed chain is a little wider than 9 speed and the FD will be a little wider but it's not much wider and will move your chain pretty nice. It's not affecting the shifter cable pull and FD move.
The problem in mixing 8 & 9 gears is in rear shifter.

Comment: Cool, I will try it out when I get the 8 speed FD.

Comment: I tried and it worked pretty well. I am now running 9 speed RD and chain, 8 speed FD, 10 speed road double crank set, 10 speed front shifter.

Comment: Ummm front shifter can't be 10 speed ;) . While the crank is called 10 speed because it's affected by the chain thickness, the derailleur also affected - as it's cage should be narrower, the shifter only affected by front derailleur speeds - i.e. 2 speed shifter.